# TcpClient don't send data to Logstash until tcp stream is closed

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, .net-core, logstash, tcpclient

I'm trying to write data into logstash via TcpClient. Code works fine, but logstash shows only last sended record and only after tcp stream is closed.

```cs
_client = new TcpClient();
_client.Connect(_settings.Host, _settings.Port);
var stream = _client.GetStream();
stream.Write(encoded, 0, encoded.Length);
stream.Flush();
```

Logstash tcp settings:

```
input{
    tcp{
        type=>"app"
        port=>"9876"
    }
}
```

What is my problem? Wrong code or wrong logstash settings

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but I cannot recommend `serilog` enough. It has a sink that ships directly to [elasticsearch](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch).

Comment: I've already chose serilog for my project, but we use ELK for logging, and it's not so good idea to write logs directly to elasticsearch in this case. So I want to develop custom sink for logstash with tcp connection. I finded several sinks, but they aren't suitable for me for a number of reasons.

Comment: why do you think it's not a good idea to write logs directly to ELK? Multiple companies I have worked for do it. It's fantastic! You're cutting out the middleman.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my decision. We use logstash to deliver data to elasticsearch and elasticsearch to storage it. By the way many people recommends to work with logs in this way. I think this is because logstash greatly simplifies logging in elasticsearch, especially with a micro-service architecture. Anyway the timing was tight, so I changed connection from tcp to http. But I'm still wondering why a tcp connection behaves with a logstash this way!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post, but thought of posting a solution to those out there who might have the same problem. In my opinion, the easiest way of sending C# Log data to LogStash over TCP is as follows.

```
#From logstash configs 
input{
  tcp{
    port=>"9876"
    codec=>"json"
  }
}
```

From the C# side, we need to create a json string to be sent to logstash. First create a LogJson.cs class and override the ToString(). This class will simply return the formatted json string required.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FeedLogstash
{
  class LogJson
  {
    public readonly int Id;
    public readonly DateTime DateTime;
    public readonly string Message;

    public LogJson(int id, DateTime dateTime, string message) {
        Id=id; DateTime=dateTime;  Message=message;
    }

    public override string ToString()  {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
  }
}
```

We can now send the above json string to LogStash tcp input. I'm using a C# SimpleTcpClient class to create the simple connection. Note- You must close the connection to write the data.

```
using SimpleTCP;
...
public void PushData() {
  LogJson log = new LogJson(1001, DateTime.Now, "Danger: Will Robinson");
  SimpleTcpClient _client;
  _client = new SimpleTcpClient().Connect(host, port);
  _client.Write(log.ToString() + "\n");
  _client.Disconnect();
}
```

Hope this helps anyone wanting to push log data over TCP from C#. I believe this same algorithm can be adopted to Java.

Answer (score 0):

Adding new line to the end of the string should allow to use single TcpClient connection.